# tikz execution order of transformation

Tags: tikz-styles

Is the execution order of transformation that if the transformation command is after `\tikz@addtransform`, it will be performed after otherwise right now?

This question rises from following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  base/.style={
    minimum height=5mm, minimum width=15mm, draw, rotate=#1
  },
  A/.style={base=#1},
  B/.style={base=#1, below=1cm},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [A=90] (a) at (0, 0) {};
  \node [B=90, red] (b) at (a.south) {};
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
  \node [B=90, blue] (b) at (a.south) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I looked up the code in `tikz.code.tex` and `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex`. The difference I find is the shift transformation code:

`tikz.code.tex` has a `\tikz@addtransform` before transformation operation

```
\tikzoption{below}[]{\def\tikz@anchor{north}\tikz@possibly@transform{y}{-}{#1}}%
\def\tikz@possibly@transform#1#2#3{%
  \let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax%
  \def\tikz@test{#3}%
  \ifx\tikz@test\pgfutil@empty%
  \else%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{#3}%
    \pgf@x=#2\pgf@x\relax%
    \edef\tikz@marshal{\noexpand\tikz@addtransform{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname  pgftransform#1shift\endcsname{\the\pgf@x}}}%
    \tikz@marshal%
  \fi%
}%
```

while `tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex` does not have a `\tikz@addtransform` before the transformation

```
\tikzset{below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north}{0}{-1}{south}{1}}%
\def\tikz@lib@place@handle@#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
  \def\tikz@anchor{#2}%
  \let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax%
  \edef\tikz@temp{#1}%
  \def\tikz@lib@place@single@factor{#6}%
  \expandafter\tikz@lib@place@handle@@\expandafter{\tikz@temp}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}%
\def\tikz@lib@place@handle@@#1#2#3#4{%
  \pgfutil@in@{of }{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tikz@lib@place@of#1\tikz@stop{#4}%
  \else%
    \edef\tikz@lib@place@nums{#1}%
  \fi%
  \ifx\tikz@lib@place@nums\pgfutil@empty%
    Ok, nothing to do, we have set the anchor and we are happy...
  \else%
    \expandafter\tikz@lib@place@parse@nums\expandafter{\tikz@lib@place@nums}%
    \pgf@x=#2\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=#3\pgf@y%
    \edef\tikz@lib@pos@call{\noexpand\pgftransformshift{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\pgf@x}{\the\pgf@y}}}%
  \fi%
}%
```

If the real reason is what I guessed, why `positioning` does not use a `\tikz@addtransform`?

Comment: I think you are right. `\tikz@addtransform` is defined as `\def\tikz@addtransform#1{%
  \ifx\tikz@transform\relax
    #1%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@transform\expandafter{\tikz@transform#1}%
  \fi
}%` so it adds a transformation to `\tikz@transform` that gets executed later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right. One can look up `\tikz@addtransform`,

```
\def\tikz@addtransform#1{%
  \ifx\tikz@transform\relax
    #1%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@transform\expandafter{\tikz@transform#1}%
  \fi
}%
```

so it adds a transformation to `\tikz@transform` that gets executed later. Apart from the effect you have mentioned, this effect also can be seen when updating the `node distance`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={circle,draw,inner sep=10pt},node distance=2cm]
 \node (A) at (0,2){};
 \node[right of=A,blue] (A-1){};
 \node[right of=A,node distance=4cm,dashed,red] (A-2){};
 \node[node distance=4cm,right of=A,dashed,cyan,inner sep=20pt] (A-3){};
 \node (B) at (0,0){};
 \node[right=of B,blue] (B-1){};
 \node[right=of B,node distance=4cm,dashed,red] (B-2){};
 \node[node distance=4cm,right=of B,dashed,cyan,inner sep=20pt] (B-3){};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, when you use the built in (but deprecated) way of positioning nodes relatively, it does not matter if you update the `node distance` before or after `right`. On the other hand, if you use `positioning`, it does.

In principle, one could think of using `\tikz@addtransform` also in the `positioning` library. However, this will break existing coded. See, however [issue 869](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/869) which deals with the question whether or not one should make changes.

Comment: Why it matters when I use the built in way to set `below` before or after `rotate`, is it different from `node distance`?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck No, I think these are the same effects. (The only difference is that when one changes the order of rotations and translations, the results differ: `\node[rotate=90,xshift=1cm,red] (C-1){};
 \node[xshift=1cm,rotate=90,blue] (C-1){};`, so it is perhaps slightly less obvious to see what is going on. So I wanted to add another way of showing that you are right, which does not involve rotations. But qualitatively it is the same effect.)

Comment: Get it, thanks a lot